# Placement of QComboBox inside QTableView

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt5

I'm trying to use a `QComboBox` as a item delegate to update a field in my `QTableView`. The editor, selection, and model data are all working fine. However, the problem is that when I click on the cell, the QComboBox does not open inside the cell. Instead it opens somewhere outside the main GUI (see attached screenshot). Any ideas how I can fix this beahvior?

I have also added a `QSpinBox` for column Freq/Qty and they are showing up properly in the cell when I double click for editing.

Note the combo box on the top left of the image.

[image]

My code:

```
        ...
        hb = QTableView()
        hbm = HierBlocksDataModel()
        hb.setModel(hbm)
        hb.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(25)
        lbd = LibraryBoxDelegate(hb)
        hb.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, lbd)
        ...

class LibraryBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent, node=None):
        super(LibraryBoxDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.node = node

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):

        if self.node is not None:
            cb = QComboBox()
            cb.addItems(list('abc'))
            return cb

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setCurrentText(index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.currentText(), Qt.EditRole)
```

Comment: you are creating a new combo box each time the method is called without assigining it to a parent or placing it anywhere within your app.  What did you expect to happen? create a [mre]

Comment: Typo: the widget needs to be created with parent in order to be shown *inside* it: change to `cb = QComboBox(parent)`. Also, you should always return the base implementation in any other case, so also add a `return super().createEditor(parent, option, index)` in the main indentation of the `createEditor()` definition.

Comment: @user4979733 Please read more about [Object Trees & Ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html): "A child normally also becomes a child widget, i.e. it is displayed in its parent's coordinate system and is graphically clipped by its parent's boundaries." A widget created without parent and not "reparented" (which is what normally happens when adding a widget to a layout), is, by default, a *top level widget*, aka: a window.